# KQL query for Time chart

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I have used this query, but I cannot get the time chart to show the trend of the CPU. appears to be only showing the current cpu. my objective is to show the trend from each computer(host)

```
 Telemetry_system
 | where hostname_s contains "computer-A"
 | where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
 | summarize
  by
 hostname,
 callBackUrl,
 cpu_d
 | summarize Aggregatedcpu= avg(cpu_d) by hostname, callBackUrl
 | render timechart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, try this:

```
Telemetry_system
| where hostname_s contains "computer-A"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
| summarize Aggregatedcpu = avg(cpu_d) by strcat(hostname, "_", callBackUrl), bin(TimeGenerated, 1s)
| render timechart
```

Comment: make-series? :-)

Comment: Most questions that can be answered by using `make-series` can also be answered by using `summarize`, and vice versa. The author of the question hasn't indicated any data point that suggests one should be preferred over the other. You're more than welcome to provide an alternative answer, and let the author choose his preferred one